# Search for word in text file and display (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, search, words

I'm trying to take input from the user, search through a text file (case insensitively), and then display the match from the file if it matches (with the case of the word in the file).  I don't know how to get the word from the file, here's my code:

```
found = 0
words = [] 

puts "Please enter a word to add to text file"
input = gets.chomp

#Open text file in read mode 
File.open("filename", "r+") do |f|

  f.each do |line|
    if line.match(/\b#{input}\b/i)
      puts "#{input} was found in the file."   # <--- I want to show the matched word here
      #Set to 1 indicating word was found
      found = 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually match your comment.  Running precisely your code I do not see the bug that you describe.  A word on subsequent lines in the file is correctly reported as found.

Comment: Also, FWIW, after doing what I imagine were the changes to your code I can't reproduce your first problem either.  Ie. after removing the split, the `for x` loop, and replacing `x` with `input` - if a word exists twice on the same line then it's only printed once.

Comment: OK but if you replace x with line then it prints out the entire line instead of just the one word. How do you just print out the one word found in the file?

Comment: Replace `x` with `input` as I said.  Do `input.downcase` if you want to display the inputted word in lowercase.

Comment: replacing x with input on the puts line just displays the word that they entered not the word in the file. I want it to display 'GoOd' if its in the file and the user inputted 'good'

Comment: :)  It's the same characters, the fact that it's the data that they input rather than the data from the file doesn't matter, you've got a match, you know you want to output whatever they entered.

Comment: Ok, so in that case you need to capture the output of the regex, and display that.  Let me edit your question, and then I'll answer it.

Comment: There, does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you want to do is to store the result of the `match` method, you can then get the actual matched word out of that, ie.

```
if m = line.match( /\b#{input}\b/i )
  puts "#{m[0]} was found in the file."
  # ... etc.
end
```

#### Update

Btw, you didn't ask - but I would use `scan` in this case, so that I got an array of the matched words on each line (for when there's more than one match on the same line), something like this:

```
if m = line.scan( /\b#{input}\b/i )
  puts "Matches found on line #{f.lineno}: #{m.join(', ')}"
  # ... etc.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to report the locations of the matches and the file is not overly large, you could just do this:

```
File.read("testfile").scan /\b#{input}\b/i
```

Let's try it:

```
text = <<THE_END
Now is the time for all good people
to come to the aid of their local
grocers, because grocers are important
to our well-being.  One more thing.
Grocers sell ice cream, and boy do I
love ice cream.
THE_END

input = "grocers"
F_NAME = "text"
File.write(F_NAME, text)

File.read(F_NAME).scan /\b#{input}\b/i
  # => ["grocers", "grocers", "Grocers"]
```

`File.read(F_NAME)` returns the entire text file in a single string. `scan /\b#{input}\b/i` is sent to that string.

Comment: I try to scan word from text file which are start from specific text such as "aa1 " , "aa2" , "aa3" . So "aa" is common for all words and I want to get all words which are start from "aa" how can i do this??