# How do I print list of files that contain certain words or phrases that is put by the user?

Tags: ruby

I need to get two inputs from user 
"Phrases or words" and "Directory"
and then I need to  read every single ".txt" files from that directory and look for the files with these phrases.
Then print the list of documents that contain the "phrases". 
I'm having trouble understanding the logic flowchart and the coding.

I tried it on @AptanaStudio Ruby. This is far as I can go for now.

```
 def ListDocument
        puts "Enter a phrase or a term"
        phrase = STDIN.gets.chomp!
        puts "Enter a directory"
        directory = STDIN.gets.chomp!
        file = directory+"./txt"
        if !File.exist?(file)
          puts "File don't exist"
        else
          File.open(file,'r')
          inputs = File.read(file)
          if inputs=~/phrase/
        end
        end
```

I expect list of document outputs.

Comment: Take a look at this [search-for-word-in-text-file-and-display-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419342/search-for-word-in-text-file-and-display-ruby) in your conditional you could have an array and save the name of the file if the word you're looking for is in it (that's what I understand you're trying to do)

I also recommend that you refactor that method, split it into different methods with one single purpose each.

Comment: `file = directory+"./txt"` won't be correct. However you can use `Dir.glob("#{directory}/*.txt").each` to iterate through the files. Also, use `Regexp.new(phrase)` not `/phrase/`, which will match the literal text "phrase". Or you can just use `include?(phrase)`